# Static data member in an unnamed class C++

Tags: c++

I read in the below link that unnamed(anonymous) class should not have static data memebers in it. Could anyone please let me know the reason for it?

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbclx01/cplr038.htm
says the below..

> You can only have one definition of a static member in a program.
>   Unnamed classes, classes contained within unnamed classes, and local
>   classes cannot have static data members.

Comment: How would you refer to the member when the class has no name?

Comment: @molbdnilo You can refer to it from within the class, but the problem is as the answer describes that the actual definition for it is required to be done from outside.

Comment: @molbdnilo `struct { int x; }  a_variable; &decltype(a_variable)::x` works so there's no reason `decltype(a_variable)::static_data_member;` couldn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All `static` member data, if they are ODR-used, must be defined outside the class/struct.

```
struct Foo
{
    static int d;
};

int Foo::d = 0;
```

If the class/struct is unnamed, there is no way to define the member outside the class.

```
int ::d = 0;
```

cannot be used to define the static member of an unnamed class.

#### Update for C++17

If you are able to use C++17 or newer, you may use

```
static inline int d = 10;
```

That will allow a `static` member variable to be defined in an anonymous `class`/`struct`.

Sample code to demonstrate that a `static` member variable need not be defined outside the class definition:

```
#include <iostream>
struct foo
{
    static inline int d = 10;
};

int main()
{
   auto ptr = &foo::d;
   std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Command to build:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall    socc.cc   -o socc
```

Output of running the program:

```
10
```

---

Thanks are due to @Jean-MichaëlCelerier for the suggestion for the update.

Comment: In C++17 we have static inline which removes this restriction: 

struct Foo { static inline int d; };

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier, good to know. Do you know whether that is enough for an ODR-used `static` member variable?

Comment: sure: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h7xMrsdcd ; it's the linker job to make sure that there is only one instance of `d` in the final program.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the standard actually forbids this?

As mentioned the problem arises as you need to have an actual definition of the static member. The language provides for no method to define it. There is no other problems in referring to it as we can do it from within the `struct` or via an instance of it.

However GCC for example will accept the following:

```
static struct {
    static int j;
} a;

int main() {
    return a.j; // Here we actually refers to the static variable
}
```

but it can't be linked as `a.j` refers to an undefined symbol (`._0::j`), but there's a way to get around this. By defining it in assembler or by using compiler extensions you could. For example adding the line

```
int j asm("_ZN3._01jE") = 42;
```

Will make it work. `_ZN3._01jE` is the real mangled name of the static variable in this case, neither the mangled or unmangled name can be used directly as a identifier in standard C++ (but it can via GCC extension or assembler).

As you must probably realize this would only work with specific compilers. Other compilers would mangle the name in other ways (or even do other things that may make the trick not work at all).

You should really question why you would like to use this trick. If you can do the work using standard methods you should most probably chose that. For example you could reduce the visibility by using anonymous `namespace` instead for example:

```
namespace {
    static struct Fubar {
         static int j;
    } a;

    Fubar::a = 0;
}
```

Now `Fubar` is not really anonymous, but it will at least be confined to the translation unit.

Comment: I seriously hope this is never used in actual production code. While it probably works, you'll get strange errors if you use a different compiler.

Comment: @HiGuy No, not that strange - you'll probably get an undefined symbol since the name would differ. Using compiler specific behavior in production code is in some circumstances acceptable (IMHO). However I can not give an reasonable reason for using this particular trick.

Comment: Production code is in most cases linked with one compiler only, sometimes one compiler version only, and one platform. This is perfectly ok.

Comment: @g24l He was not implying that more than one compiler/linker would be used to generate a deployment, but that when you are compiling a package for several platforms, you will require several compilers.  Errors that one compiler let slide may not slide on other compilers, leading to a complicated web of cross-compiler issues to resolve.  Doing "funky" things like this is *never* "okay" - they should be avoided unless there is absolutely no other way to solve a given problem (highly unlikely).

Comment: @ZacHowland , hm, portability is not always a requirement you know.

Comment: @ZacHowland Keep in mind that I didn't claim that there were a actual use for this particular trick. However there **are** situation where portability is not a requirement. There **are** situations which you can't solve in a portable way. Maybe you don't run into them in a cozy java desktop environment, or at least you don't see them. In embedded programming, OS programming and other low level fields you're more likely to run in to tasks that's will tend to use non-portable techniques (and portability is then not a issue).

Comment: @skyking It isn't a matter of portability.  It is a matter of taking advantage of errors in specific compilers, which makes your code less maintainable.  And the 2 examples provided (embedded and OS) are completely inaccurate (if you've ever done anything with the Linux kernel, you'd see exactly why these kinds of situations are avoided - Linus went on a tirade when someone checked in low level code that took advantage of a specific compiler's faults to solve an issue).

Comment: @ZacHowland First as I've pointed out I think I was clear that I don't see a situation that justify this particular trick. Second I think it's wrong to call them both inaccurate - what's the inaccuracy in the second? To call compiler specific extensions faults is a bit harsh in my opinion. If you consider that it would be a bit hypocritical from Linus since the source already makes use of GCC specific extensions.

Comment: @skyking When you write you code to take advantage of a compiler-specific extension/fault you end up with code that is less maintainable.  That is, the next person who looks at your code has to know you used this, and keep a watch out for when/if the compiler being used changes/fixes the non-standard usage.  You listed OS and embedded as two places this is common.  Having worked in both:  it is highly discouraged in both, unless there is absolutely no other way (and the chances of that happening are about the same as winning the Powerball jackpot).

Comment: @ZacHowland That's depend on what you mean by "no other way". There's always another way (fx write a binary blob), but it would not always be more maintainable just because you avoid compiler-specifics. My experience is that there's plenty of cases where it's OK to use compiler-specifics (IMHO). Why else was they implemented and documented?

Comment: @ZacHowland , using compiler extensions is perfectly legal. As has been pointed out there are some companies out there that don't care about these concerns because there is one compiler-linker-platform system they target, and the code is not open sources so that X-person will try to compile it. In all the other cases people tend to use #ifdef to wrap their compiler specific code.

Comment: @g24l If you reread my first comment, you'll see that I don't say it is illegal, rather it should be avoided unless there is no other way to do it.  In most cases, using a compiler-specific extension/fault is poor design and leads to maintenance headaches later.  When this is done because there was no other way to do it, it is acceptable.  When it is done because someone was too lazy to write their code properly, it is not acceptable.  Situations that fall into the former are few and far between.

Answer (score 1):

When C++ was standardized, unnamed classes could not have static data members, as there was no way to define/instantiate them. However, this problem has been solved with C++11, as it added the `decltype` operator:

```
struct {
    static int j;
} a;

// Declare the static member of the unnamed struct:
int decltype(a)::j = 42;

int main() {
    return a.j == 42 ? 0 : 1; // Use the static member 
}
```

So, in principle, there could be unnamed classes or structs with static data members. But the C++ standard makers deliberately did not allow this syntax, as the compiler doesn't know, which name it should give to that `decltype(a)::j` thing for linking. So most (all?) compilers - including current versions of GCC in normal mode - refuse to compile this.

In `-fpermissive` mode, GCC-9 und GCC-10 accept this code and compile it fine. However, if the declaration of `a` is moved to a header file, that is included from different source files, they still fail at the linking stage.

So unnamed classes can only be used inside a single translation unit. To avoid polluting the global namespace, just put anything, that needs to stay local, inside an anonymous namespace. So:

```
namespace {
    struct whatever {
        static int j;
    } a;
    int whatever::j = 42;
}
int main() {
    return a.j == 42 ? 0 : 1; 
}
```

compiles fine, doesn't pollute global namespace, and even doesn't lead to problems, if the name `whatever` clashes with a name from another header file.